# Any suggestions to use hash for postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Can I use CRC function as a hash for postgres?

Comment: Do you need CRC specifically or just a hash function?

Comment: I thinks hash would be enough. But not sure. I need CRC to detect changes for set of columns. I plan use it for Lucene and must now if record was changed.

Comment: in fact i think about MD5 but not sure that have sense in terms of performance and amount of data

Comment: I'd guess that a C MD5 will be faster than an SQL or PgSQL CRC. A C implementation of CRC would be pretty quick though. OTOH, you'd have to do some testing and measuring to see how much it mattered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any old hash function will do then PostgreSQL has an [`md5()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function built in. MD5 should be sufficient for checking if a record has changed. There's also a [binary version](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER) if you need to deal with non-textual data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment that says:

> I need CRC to detect changes for set of columns. I plan use it for Lucene and must now if record was changed.

Checking crc is a bad idea. Just add "last modified" column to your table, and update it in trigger if any of the fields got modified.

Then in your lucene feeder you can: select * from objects where last_modified > 'previous last_modified' - which is fast because it's indexed.

Comment: yep, that is great idea. only on thing, in result in have all records updated. but in fact some of them have the same data as before. that is why i think about crc

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that i can not add field "last modify". After each update process i have all updated records in result. So all records will marked with fresh date. But some of records I update by old data. For example records1 = "123" and I set "123" for it. In this reason "last mod" is not solution for me.

Comment: Just set the last_modified with trigger that checks if there were changes, and doesn't change last_modified if there were no changes in other fields.

Comment: yep. only i afraid that is real loading on performance. in this case necessary compare all fields.

Comment: don't be afraid. test. testing beats fears every time.

Comment: You can even prevent an update from happening when no fields are changed by returning NULL from the trigger. This actually might improve performance if many rows do not change and will reduce the amount of work vacuum has to do.