# Same hashing function MySQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, hash

I'm looking for an hashing function which is implemented in both PostgreSQL and MySQL, which can hash a string and return an integer.

For example I tried to use hashtext function in PostgreSQL, but I haven't found the same function implementation in MySQL.

I've seen that MySQL supports md5, but it returns a string instead of an integer.

Comment: how can a md5 return a integer?

Comment: md5 does return a string, but in my usecase I would need an integer returned.
For example, hashtext() function in postgresql does return an integer

Comment: This would go a lot better if you provided some example data and a rationale for what you are doing. *Add answers as update to question*.

Comment: i doubt that an integer will not have many collisions, you can ways program https://doxygen.postgresql.org/hashfunc_8c.html#aad567d8b982aa2cbd153cb79795271db as function or procedure to generatw

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to post a link to documentation / explanation for the `hashtext()` function you mention?

Answer (score 3):

The Postgres query

```
SELECT encode(sha224('foo'::bytea), 'hex')
```

and the MySQL query

```
SELECT SHA2('foo', 224)
```

both return the same number encoded as a hex string, `0808f64e60d58979fcb676c96ec938270dea42445aeefcd3a4e6f8db`.

MySQL has the `CRC32()` function to return an unsigned 32-bit [cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) number on a a string. You can create the same capability with a stored function in postgres. For example: [CRC32 function with PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179335/crc32-function-with-pl-pgsql)

They get the same value. [Postgres fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=13c2a9206c323b97226afe9979821c75)   [MySql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=2db25b7b5c5de93b5ef5077d126d6998).